# Problem with Ci3 Session data on Amazon Ec2 after connecting on cloudfront with route53. Works when launched on public DNS

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm having some issues with the saving session on Amazon Ec2.
I built the program with CodeIgniter3. It's working fine when I launch it on the public DNS. I then set the DNS as the origin domain name on CloudFront which is linked to my domain name on route53.
The website loads properly but the session doesn't get saved. (It still works fine accessing on the public DNS).

**What I've done so far:**

- Updated Allowed HTTP Methods to GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

And It's still not working.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by doing the following in cloudfront behavior:

1. Selecting "Use legacy cache settings" in Cache and origin request settings
2. Forward Cookies - All
3. Query String Forwarding and Caching - Forward All, Cache based on All.